# Other Trigonometric Solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have always been confused on how to get the other solution when solving trigonometric equations.
The original function is $f(x)=8\sin^2(x)-2\sin(x)-4$

$$\sin(x)=\frac{\sqrt{33}\pm1}{8}$$
$$\sin(x)=\frac{\sqrt{33}+1}{8}$$
$$x=\sin^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{33}+1}{8})$$
$$x=1.00297\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\x=?$$
$$\sin(x)=\frac{\sqrt{33}-1}{8}$$
$$x=\sin^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{33}-1}{8})$$
$$x=-.634897$$
$$x=?$$
How do I get the other solution pair of solutions? Do I subtract $1.00297$ from $\pi$, because that gets $2.13863$ which I believe is a solution, and if I did the same thing I get $3.77646$ which is a solution too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple.  Recall that

$$\sin(x+2\pi k)=\sin(x)\quad k\in\mathbb Z$$

$$\sin(x)=-\sin(-x)$$

And apply this to both of your solutions.

Comment: $k$ Is any integer.

Comment: I probably am missing the point but isn't $\sin(x+\pi k)=\pm \sin(x)$ depending on the parity of $k$

Comment: @kingW3 You are right my fine sir.

Answer (score 2):

You can also visualize the solution to equations of the form

$$ \sin\theta=y $$

geometrically with respect to the unit circle. Draw a horizontal line through any value of $y\in[-1,1]$ and note the point(s) of intersection with the unit circle. Any standard angle (vertex the origin, initial side the positive $x$-axis with terminal side containing said point(s) of intersection is a solution of the equation.

For any integer $n$ there will be two corresponding solutions:

1. $\theta=\phantom{-}\arcsin(y)+2n\pi$
2. $\theta=-\arcsin(y)+(2n+1)\pi$

[image: Illustration of solutions of sin(x)=y]

Answer (score 1):

Look at this once, 
[image]

I guess you can take it on from here, once by taking positive sign and again by taking negative sign.